# Given $\log_b5=a$ and $\log_b2.5=c$, find $x$ in terms of $a$ and $c$ if $5^x=2.5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

> Given $\log_b5=a$ and $\log_b2.5=c$, find $x$ in terms of $a$ and $c$ if $5^x=2.5$

I don't know how to get rid of $b$ in these equations. For the equation with $x$ it becomes $x=\log_52.5$ which suspiciously resembles the first two equations, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second condition gives $x\log_b5=c$ and from here $x=\frac{c}{a}$.

Because
$$c=\log_b2.5=\log_b5^x=x\log_b5=xa$$

Comment: This is good. I would like to add for clarity that you got to $x\log_b5 = c$ because $5^x = 2.5$ so you take $\log_b$ of both sides and then by the laws of logarithms, you can bring the $x$ in front of the $\log_b 5$ term.

Comment: I would have been confused without this comment lmao

Comment: @rb612 I used $c=\log_b2.5=\log_b5^x=x\log_b5=xa,$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg yep! I just wanted to clarify for OP that in order to get that $\log_b  2.5 = \log_b 5^x$, you took the logarithm base b of both sides.

Answer (score 3):

The log equations can be rearranged to:

$b^a = 5$ and $b^c = 2.5$ (definition of log)

Using the other given condition,

$(b^a)^x = b^c$

$b^{ax} = b^c$ (rules of exponentiation)

$ax = c$ (the exponential function is one to one)

$x = \frac ca$

Comment: Thanks! $\!\!\!$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $5^x=2.5$ is equivalent to $x=\log_5(2.5)$. By properties of the logarithmic functions one has $$\log_5(2.5)=\frac{\log_b (2.5)}{\log_b (5)}=\frac{c}{a},$$ hence $x=\frac{c}{a}$.

Comment: Oh wow just change of base and I'm done how did I not notice this

Answer (score 0):

Hello: First note that $$5^x =2.5 \iff \log_5(2.5)=x$$ since the exponential and logarithmic functions are mutually inverse.

Now, since $\log_b(5)=a$ and $\log_b(2.5)=c$ then by properties of logarithms:
$$ \log_5(2.5)=\frac{\log_b(2.5)}{\log_b(5)}=\frac{c}{a}.$$ In other words $x=\dfrac{c}{a}$.